# printing updating variable in c

Tags: c, variables, printing, timer

I need to make a counter in c and Im having kind of a noobish question. Here is my code :

```
 time_t start = time((time_t *) NULL);
  time_t finish = start;
  while((finish-start) < 5){
        finish=time((time_t *)NULL);
        printf("TIME : %d\n", (finish-start));
  }   
  printf("TIMER HAS STOPED !");
```

What i whant is to show the value of (finish-start) Like : TIMER : value, with the "value" beeing updated according to the variables, but i what "TIMER" to remain on screen and only the value to update. Like it is now it writes TIME: value about 1 million times on the screen.
Thx in advance :X !

Comment: Please reward the people who have helped you and [accept answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
printf("TIME : %d\r", (finish-start));
fflush (stdout);
```

But for more complex command & terminal oriented I/O, consider using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/)

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

printf("TIME : %d\n", (finish-start));

by

printf("TIME : %d\r", (finish-start));

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, take a look at [SetConconsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you are on systems that support [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/), use it.

Or, more hackish, but if it works on your system, it is very easy, use `\b` escape in printf:

`printf("%2d", i);`

`delay(400);`

`printf("\b\b");`